# Remmina - Copy stored passwords to other users

Tags: linux, remmina, alma-linux

I have configured RDP/SSH connections for different servers on one user. I have written a script that copies the `.local/share/remmina/` folder and `.config/remmina/remmina.pref` file over to the other user's directory.

The connections appear in Remmina for other users but passwords needs to be re-entered for each user. How do I copy over the passwords also?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2..3}; do
    cp /home/disorder1/Desktop/org.remmina.Remmina.desktop /home/disorder$i/Desktop
    cp -r /home/disorder1/.local/share/remmina/  /home/disorder$i/.local/share
    mkdir -p /home/disorder$i/.config/remmina
    cp /home/disorder/.config/remmina/remmina.pref  /home/disorder$i/.config/remmina
    sed -i "s/disorder/disorder$i/g" /home/disorder$i/.config/remmina/remmina.pref
    chown -R disorder$i:disorder$i /home/disorder$i/
    chmod a+x /home/disorder$i/Desktop/org.remmina.Remmina.desktop
    sudo -u disorder$i -g disorder$i dbus-launch gio set /home/disorder$i/Desktop/org.remmina.Remmina.desktop metadata::trusted yes
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it is one of the top results on Google.

I found this note on the Wiki

> How are Remmina passwords stored? Are they secure?
>
> They are encrypted using 3DES with a 256 bit randomly generated key. Keep your key secure. If you use kwallet, gnome-keyring or a similar solution, your password will be managed automatically by libsecret, which is
> superior to the aforementioned native Remmina encryption. A future solution of password and file encryption with libsodium is being implemented.

I found the passwords I was looking for in the gnome-keyring. Whether it is stored in the gnome-keyring or kwallet will depend on whether you use Gnome or KDE.

I don't know how you can export these and import it again. It will most likely end up being a copy & paste exercise, not ideal if there are a lot of them.

Comment: ...maybe guacamole might be more appropriate?